# Python dereference whole array by array

Tags: python, numpy, dereference

Is there a way to dereference a numpy array which returns the full array based on a default function argument ?
Example:

```
def return_full_array(array, arg=default_value):
    return array[default_value]
```

Where array[default_value] is the same array as array, i.e. the full array again. The point is to set an default value to arg which will give me the unchanged array back **without if cases** to check what arg is.

Comment: You can use `slice(None)` as `default_value`, although that will return a copy of `array`.

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to use if? 'if arg is None' would make this bit easier to read and understand.

Comment: This does work. Can i somehow accept the comment as answer ? This was inteded as reply to jdehesa.<br> For Jarek.D: I was mostly curious if there is a way without an if case. I use the arg as a condition to slice the first array and was interested if i could avoid the if case by a default argument if the user doesn't specify a condition.